# error when compilling TWRP for VTR P10

Tags: twrp, linux, huawei, python

i'm using manjaro linux
i/m trying to compile TWRP for Huawei p10 vtr-l09
i'm using this repo:
https://github.com/minimal-manifest-twrp/platform_manifest_twrp_omni?tab=readme-ov-file
and this is the device tree:
https://github.com/josip-k/android_device_huawei_vtr
after:

```
cd twrp
export ALLOW_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES=true
```

when i try to build twrp i get:

```
./build/envsetup.sh
zsh: permission denied: ./build/envsetup.sh
```

when i try with root privileges i get:

```
sudo ./build/envsetup.sh
sudo: ./build/envsetup.sh: command not found
```

so where is the problem?